# Img Path is Required error in ASP.NET MVC using EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am inserting the Product, Image, and Product Detail, everything is fine but when I insert image then I get an error. ImagePath is not inserting when I use extra table image then this error occur, if I use column imgpath in Product then it's working, I use extra table beacuase I want to insert multiple images that's why I use extra table.

The error is:

> imgPath is required

When I use breakpoint I can see the image then the cursor will reach on save function I don't the values in image object.

Can any expert tell me where I am wrong? If you any easy solution kindly guide me.

Image:

```
public partial class Image
{
    public int imgID { get; set; }
    public string ImgName { get; set; }
    public bigint prodid{ get; set; }
}
```

Product model:

```
public partial class Product
{
    public long ProductID { get; set; }
    public string PName { get; set; }
    public string PDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Product master detail:

```
public partial class MasterDetail
{
    public int mDID { get; set; }
    public long ProductID { get; set; }
    public string OS { get; set; }
    public string SimType { get; set; }
    public string Other { get; set; }
}
```

Product interface:

```
public interface IProduct
{
    void Add_NewProduct(Product prod, Specification spec, Image pic);
}
```

Product implementation:

```
public void Add_NewProduct(Product prod, Specification spec, Image pic)
{
    try
    {
        _db.Products.Add(prod);
        _db.Specifications.Add(spec);
        _db.Images.Add(pic);

        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Product controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddNewProducts(ProductViewModel prod, List<HttpPostedFileBase> file)
{
    try
    {
        List<ProductType> PTlist = _IproductType.PTList();
        ViewBag.Ptlist = new SelectList(PTlist, "PType_ID", "P_Name");

        // Product Color List
        List<P_Color> pColorList = _IProductColor.PColorlist();
        ViewBag.pColor_List = new SelectList(pColorList, "C_ID", "C_Name_OR_Code");

        List<P_Size> pSizeList = _ISize.pSizeList();
        ViewBag.pSizeLists = new SelectList(pSizeList, "S_ID", "S_Size");

        string PathDB = string.Empty;

        foreach (HttpPostedFileBase files in file)
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(files.FileName);
            string _filename = DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssff") + filename;
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(files.FileName);
            string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Upload/"), _filename);

            PathDB = "~/Upload/" + _filename;

            if (extension.ToLower() == ".jpeg" || extension.ToLower() == ".jpg" || extension.ToLower() == ".png")
            {
                if (files.ContentLength <= 1000000)
                {
                    img = new Image();
                    prod.ImgID = img.imgID;
                    prod.ImgPath = PathDB;
                    prod.ProductID = img.ProdID;
                }
                else
                    ViewBag.sizemsg = "Size Limit accessed ";
            }
            else
                ViewBag.fileformat = "File is not Format is not Correct";
        }

        Product pro = new Product();
        pro.ProductID = prod.ProductID;
        pro.PName = prod.PName;
        pro.PDescription = prod.PDescription;

        Specification p_spec = new Specification();
        p_spec.PSpecificationID = prod.PSpecificationID;
        p_spec.ProductID = prod.ProductID;
        p_spec.OS = prod.OS;
        p_spec.DualSim = prod.DualSim;
        p_spec.TouchScreen = prod.TouchScreen;
        p_spec.Other = prod.Other;

        _IProducts.Add_NewProduct(pro, p_spec, img);

        ViewBag.message = "Record Saved Successfully";
        ModelState.Clear();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return RedirectToAction("ProductsList");
}
```

Product view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddNewProducts", "Items", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
            {    <div id="tabimage" class="tab-pane">
                                <h3 class="mgtp-15 mgbt-xs-20"> Images</h3>

                                    <div class="vd_panel-menu">
                                        <div> <a class="btn vd_btn vd_bg-blue btn-sm save-btn"><i class="fa fa-save append-icon"></i> Save Changes</a> <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-times append-icon"></i> Cancel Changes</a></div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-lg-3 file_upload_label"> <span title="" data-toggle="tooltip" class="label-tooltip" data-original-title="Format JPG, GIF, PNG. Filesize 8.00 MB max."> Add a new image to this product </span> </label>
                                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                                            <span class="btn vd_btn vd_bg-green fileinput-button">
                                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> <span>Add files...</span>
                                                <!-- The file input field used as target for the file upload widget -->
                                                <input type="file" name="file" required="required" multiple id="file" />

                                            </span> 
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>   }
```

Comment: Firstly: Where did you create `img` variable?  
Secondly: You are assigning `img` to an Image. But nothing more. Because of that it's always going null to `addNewProduct` method.  
  
Can you try the set the values of `img` and save the product again ?